# How to maintain a nice logo in a fix height div?

Tags: css, html, image

I want to have a nice looking box **AND** a nice looking logo in that box (logos are for example purpose only).

BUT I don't know how to do that.

I have my image tag look like this

```
<img class="col-sm-12 pull-right" src="/marketing_materials/{{$marketing_material->id}}/download/thumb_path" alt="" />
```

If I include the `width="200"` `height="200"` in the `<img>` tag, my view will look like this.

[image]

I got a nice looking box, but ugly logo(stretch).

Else if I include the `width="200"` only in the `<img>` tag, my view will look like this.

[image]

I got a nice looking logo, but ugly box(doesn't line up).

Either way, I chose will screw up my view. :(

Comment: What kind of box are you trying to put it in?

Comment: You need images that will fit the same size box while still maintaining their ratio. In the first examples there are just stretched and they do no respect the ratio and you get the ugly extension. Try to find pictures that will fit in 200x200 while maintaining ratio.

Comment: Set the size on the div box, not on the image

Comment: @SamHuckaby : box ? I'm trying to put in here. `<div class="col-sm-12" > ..// my image </div> `

Comment: @Azael : I was thinking the same thing as you suggested, but nothing seem to take effect ! :(

Comment: @CodeWhisperer : I agree 100%, but my goal, I don't want to do that because it's gonna be a little more works for my users. Do you have other options ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put your image in a 200x200 div and center your image (but not stretch it) inside it like this:

```css
.imgbox{
    border:solid 4px grey;
    border-radius:5px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle 
}
```

```html
<div class="imgbox">
    <img src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100520131746/logopedia/images/5/5c/Google_logo.png">
</div>
```

Comment: You will need to add `overflow: hidden`

Comment: A little weird that you’re using the border shorthand and then overriding it with `border-color`. Any particular reason you didn’t just do `border: 4px solid grey`?

Comment: @Zaqx Just: don't know :D

Comment: One last comment, this approach is a hack that while works may bring with it unintended consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `background-size` property is the simplest way.

Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0 }

figure.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/F0RRqFy.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<figure class="logo"></figure>
```

Editable Demo: http://jsbin.com/gituzu/2/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

you can center the images horizontal and vertical to the parent width and height by using `position: absolute;`:

HTML:

```
<div class="img_wrap">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/453545705622106112/6ERHbJBN.jpeg" />
</div>
<div class="img_wrap">
    <img src="http://wottageek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Dropbox-Logo.png" />
</div>  
<div class="img_wrap">
    <img src="https://longren.io/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/do.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img_wrap
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
}

.img_wrap img
{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/82bhzxfe/